# Closed Checkout callback parameters available?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I’ve got a Stripe Checkout custom integration which calls a function when closed during the payment process. Is it possible to get the email address he entered so I can email him afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `closed` callback won't return any parameter and there would be no guarantee that he even filled the email address anyway so that wouldn't be possible.